Error while sending email via lightning emaill template through apex
    // Now to check contact counts
    For(Account acc : accountsMap.values()){
        Integer actualContactCount = acc.Contacts.size();
        Integer expectedContactCount = Integer.valueOf(acc.Number_of_Contacts__c);

        if (actualContactCount != expectedContactCount) {
        // Email to the accounts email address
        EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id, Subject, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'Contacts'];
        List toAddress = new List();
        toAddress.add(acc.Account_Email__c);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
   
        mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddress);
        mail.setTargetObjectId(acc.AccountId); // This is the person receiving the email. Has to be User, Contact, Lead, or Person objects - or you will get INVALID_TYPE_FOR_OPERATION error. 
        mail.setWhatId(acc.Id); // Id of the Quote record. 
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        mail.setUseSignature(false);
   
        List allmsg = new List();
        allmsg.add(mail);
   
        try {
             Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg,false);
             return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As per the documentation,

The ID of the contact, lead, or user to which the email will be sent.
The ID you specify sets the context and ensures that merge fields in
the template contain the correct data.

Do not specify the IDs of records that have the Email Opt Out option selected.

All emails must have a recipient value in at least one of the
following fields: toAddresses, ccAddresses, bccAddresses, targetObjectId

You have set a target object ID as an account ID. Change it to the user, lead or contact ID.
mail.setTargetObjectId(acc.AccountId); //change the account Id to contact, lead, or user Id.

